# How to avoid this python dependency?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependencies

I have a python Presenter class that has a method which creates an instance of a different Presenter class:

```
class MainPresenter(object):
    def showPartNumberSelectionDialog(self, pn):
        view = self.view.getPartNumberSelectionDialog(pn)
        dialog = SecondPresenter(self.model, view)
        dialog.show()
```

my intent was to write a separate Presenter class for each window in my application, in order to keep things orderly. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to test the `showPartNuberSelectionDialog` method, particularly to test that `dialog.show()` was called, because the instance is created within the method call. So, even if I patch `SecondPresenter` using python's mock framework, it still doesn't catch the call to the local `dialog` instance.

So, I have a two questions:

1. How can I change my approach in order to make this code more testable?
2. Is it considered good practice to test simple code blocks such as this?

Comment: You certainly can patch SecondPresenter here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to patch `SecondPresenter` and check both how you call it and  if your code call `show()` too.

By use [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) framework and [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) you should replace `SecondPresenter` class instance by a `Mock` object. Take care the `dialog` instance will be the return value of the mock used to replace the original class instance. Moreover you should take care of [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), now I can just guess how to do it but it will not far from the final test version:

```
@patch("mainpresentermodule.SecondPresenter", autospec=True)
def test_part_number_selection_dialog(self, mock_second_presenter_class):
    main = MainPresenter()
    main.showPartNumberSelectionDialog(123456)
    dialog = mock_second_presenter_class.return_value
    dialog.show.assert_called_with()
```

I used `autospec=True` just because I consider it a best practice, take a look to [Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) for more details.

You can also patch `main.view` and `main.model` to test how your code call `dialog`'s constructor... but you should use mock and not abuse of it, more things you mock and patch and more your tests will be tangled to the code.

---

For the second question I think it is a good practice test these kind of block also, but try to patch and mock too far as possible and just what you can not use in testing environment: you will have a more flexible tests and you'll can refactor your code by rewriting less test code.